# Non-target attribute is imbalanced, is it class imbalance or is there another term?

Tags: terminology, unbalanced-classes, discrete-data

I have come across the term *class imbalance* in classification problems. From what I understand, it means the target variable is split into two (or more) categories where on category is significantly smaller than the other(s).

An example of this arises when detecting bank fraud, the number of 'honest' customers outnumber the fraudsters by more than one order of magnitude.

I am asking about a different kind of imbalance. Suppose we are still detecting bank fraud, but we are looking at people from different continents:

> one million Americans, one million Europeans and 100 thousand Asians.

Now we are faced with data in which the Asians (which is a value of a non-target attribute) are underrepresented in the data. Is this imbalance also called *class imbalance* or is there a more suiting term? The reason I'm asking is because in this situation there is still *normal* class imbalance (the number of fraudsters are still significantly outnumbered by the non-fraudsters) and I want to address both issues.

If possible, I would like to use two terms:

> class imbalance: to refer to the fact that the fraudsters are outnumbered by the *honest* customers, and
>
> *`some term`*: to refer to the fact that the Europeans and the Americans each outnumber the Asians in the data set.

Does any such term exist? If not, how is this issue normally referred to?